# How to (get and) compare previous state value with a new value inside useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I put the simplified version of my case above. I'm trying to compare the new network result with the previous version of it. I store fetched data in the state as 'notifications'. I don't want to `setNotifications` if there is no change.

In useEffect dependency array, eslint yells and wants me to put the `notifications` array into the dep array. But I'm changing `notifications` in useEffect. If I'm not wrong, it will be an endless loop. Because notifications are an object array and they change in each render (even if there is no real change in data)

Could you explain which mental model should I follow when using useEffect in this scenario?

```
const NotificationBox = () => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    client.get('notification?count=10').then((newResult) => {
      if (!_.isEqual(notifications, newResult)) {
        //notifications is stale
        setNotifications(newResult)
      }
    })
  }, [iHaveSomethingDifferentThatTriggersThisEffect]) 
  //Also, ESLint: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'notifications'. Either include it or 
    remove the dependency array.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
}

export default NotificationBox
```

Comment: The essence of adding a dep array is for the useEffect life hook to know when to re-render, adding notifications to it shouldn't give an endless loop since you have an if statement in there.

Comment: What if `notifications` change anywhere in the app? It gets fetching every time for no reason.

Comment: If you update `notifications` from somewhere else there is a chance your hook could run with a stale state. Most likely very low chances of that making a difference... but it's still a code smell in my world. I would encapsulate this in a custom hook and store the actual value in a ref to make it robust and resilient.

Comment: Notifications won't change unless you call the `setNotifications` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @super Can you give me an example of it? @dev_integral what if I call `setNotifications`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your code will work fine... **almost** all the time.

If `notifications` is updated and the fetch is triggered at the same time your hook runs the risk of running with a stale value.

I think you can do better. You could for example make a custom hook to encapsulate the behaviour.

```
const notificationsCache = {
    current: []
}

export function useNotifications() {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState(notificationsCache.current)

    const update = useCallback(() => {
        client.get('notification?count=10').then((newResult) => {
            if (!_.isEqual(notificationsCache.current, newResult)) {
                notificationsCache.current = newResult
                setNotifications(notificationsCache.current)
            }
        })
    }, [])

    return [notifications, update]
}
```

This uses and exernal "ref" to cache the result, so all the component using the hook will share a cache. If that's not desired, you can just move the cache into the component with a `useRef` instead and every component will have an independent cache.

```
export function useNotifications() {
    const notificationsCache = useRef([])
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState(notificationsCache.current)

    const update = useCallback(() => {
        client.get('notification?count=10').then((newResult) => {
            if (!_.isEqual(notificationsCache.current, newResult)) {
                notificationsCache.current = newResult
                setNotifications(notificationsCache.current)
            }
        })
    }, [])

    return [notifications, update]
}
```

Then we just can

```
const [notifications, update] = useNotifications()
```

and use `update` when we want to trigger a re-fetch.

There is room to improve this more. What if you have multiple components that use the hook and are mounted at the same time. If you updates the value, the other hooks state should ideally also get updated.

A perfect time to use the new `useId` hook.

```
const notificationsCache = {
    current: []
}

const listeners = {}

export function useNotifications() {
    const id = useId()
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState(notificationsCache.current)

    useEffect(() => {
        listeners[id] = setNotifications

        return () => delete listeners[id]
    }, [])

    const setState = useCallback((newNotifications) => {
        notificationsCache.current = newNotifications
        for (const id in listeners) {
           listeners[id](notificationsCache.current)
        }
    }, [])

    const update = useCallback(() => {
        client.get('notification?count=10').then((newResult) => {
            if (!_.isEqual(notificationsCache.current, newResult)) {
                setState(newResult)
            }
        })
    }, [])

    return [notifications, setState, update]
}
```